# What is the difference between ./myShellScript and ~/myShellScript

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am beginner in learning shell script, I found a way to run the the script file from anywhere in file system with '~'

This is my shell script

myShellScript

```
#! /bin/bash

echo $(date): $* >> ~/notes.txt

echo $(date): $* >> ./notes.txt
```

And I run the ./myShellScript "write date to file"

I am trying to understand accessing file structure ./ and ~/

Comment: In fact, `./notes.txt` is pretty pointless because it is no different from `notes.txt` which is implicitly in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`./` is for current directory

`~/` for home directory

Comment: I didn't know the difference, but now I am. thank you